# How to make a column based on another specific column's values?

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

Hello I am trying to make a report where I have something like

```
+--------------+---------------+----------------------+-------------+
| Employee ID  | Employee Name | Manager Employee ID  | Manger Name |
+--------------+---------------+----------------------+-------------+
|      E001    |   Bob Jones   |   E005               |  Liz Bates  | 
|      E002    |   John Smith  |   E005               |  Liz Bates  | 
|      E003    |   Jane Adams  |   E005               |  Liz Bates  | 
|      E004    |    Al Doe     |   E005               |  Liz Bates  | 
|      E005    |   Liz Bates   |   E006               |  Jake Mann  |
+--------------+---------------+----------------------+-------------+
```

I have the data items for "Employee ID", "Employee Name", and "Manager Employee ID". but there is no specific item for "Manager Name".  How do i create a data item for "Manager Name" based on "Employee Name" for the given "Manager Employee ID".  When I drag in "Employee Name" again to the right of "Manager Employee ID" it just gives me the employee based on the "Employee ID" and not "Manager Employee ID".

I have this question and answer multiple times on this site but they all are for SQL, which I don't know anything about.

[SQL query to get the employee name and their manager name from the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52235524/sql-query-to-get-the-employee-name-and-their-manager-name-from-the-same-table)

[Self Join to get employee manager name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427300/self-join-to-get-employee-manager-name)

[How to get the employees with their managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451761/how-to-get-the-employees-with-their-managers)

etc.

Comment: Given the stated requirement,  what would the desired output look like?

Comment: Do you have access to Framework Manager?
if not, ask the person that created the model to add a data item for manager name
Explain they need to link the employee file to the Manager Employee ID

Answer (score 0):

Master detail relationship could be an option as a workaround

1. Make a second list of employee ID and employee name
2. Take that second list and move it into the main list on the last column where manager name should be (It should look like a list within a list)
3. Click on that second list, look for the property master detail relationship.  Click the ellipsis, link the employee manager ID from the main list to the employee id on the second list
4. Set the property for box type to none to hide the column for employee ID on the second list